# Creating a simple Java change calculator?

Tags: java, calculator

We've been given a 'Build a change calculator' project, and told its very easy coding, nothing complicated, but I'm at a loss.

I've tried the below to get quarters to return, but still getting all zeroes for everything. We were told no if/else or switch, just a simple few lines will do. **  You'll see a 'Your code goes here' part about 7 lines down in the full code:

```
quarters = amount/25;
amount = amount - quarters/25;
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void makeChange(int amount) {
        int quarters = 0;
        int dimes = 0;
        int nickels = 0;
        int pennies = 0;    
        System.out.printf("%d is:\n", amount);
        // TODO: your code goes below this line.


        // Don't change the line below.
        System.out.printf("%d quarters, %d dimes, %d nickels, %d pennies\n",
                  quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);
    }
    // Don't change the code below.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean done = false;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!done) {
            System.out.println("Enter a # between 1 and 99 (0 to stop):");
            int amount = in.nextInt();
            if (amount <= 0) {
                done = true;
            } else {
                makeChange(amount);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Can anyone assist with what needs to be done & why I'm getting anything returned?  The instructions on Eclipse setup was vague & switching the zip & workspace from class to home could be a factor, but I don't believe so. Just one more thing that may be affected my output tho so I'm a bit at a loss of the possibilities of what's wrong

Comment: Your code does not include the `quarters = amount/25; amount = amount - quarters/25;` calculation.

Comment: If you search for "[java] quarters dime" here you will find many similar questions

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't divide the quarters by 25 again when subtracting from the amount.

```
    quarters = amount/25;
    amount = amount - quarters * 25;
```

Comment: Close, but I think you meant `amount = amount - quarters * 25;`.

Comment: You are right, I edited my answer to add your correction

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the `%` or modulo operator in order to find the remainder left after you divide by the amount.  So if `amount = 76`, the remainder from dividing by `25` would be `1`, which would be your new `amount`.

I wrote out the full implementation and made sure it works, but I removed half of it so you can learn what you must do and test it for yourself.  I put in comments to guide you some.  Make sure you go in order from largest value of coin, to smallest.

```
public static void makeChange(int amount) {
    int quarters = 0;
    int dimes = 0;
    int nickels = 0;
    int pennies = 0;    
    System.out.printf("%d is:\n", amount);
    // TODO: your code goes below this line.
    quarters = amount / 25;
    amount = amount % 25;

    dimes = amount / 10;
    //Do the modulo for dimes

    //Do nickels and pennies

    // Don't change the line below.
    System.out.printf("%d quarters, %d dimes, %d nickels, %d pennies\n",
              quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
quarters = amount/25; amount = amount - quarters/25;
```

is declared before anything is stored in those variables. You need to put it where the instructor asked and then it should work.

```
public class Main {

public static void makeChange(int amount) {
    int quarters = 0;
    int dimes = 0;
    int nickels = 0;
    int pennies = 0;    
    System.out.printf("%d is:\n", amount);
    // TODO: your code goes below this line.
    quarters = amount/25; 
    amount = amount - quarters/25;

    // Don't change the line below.
    System.out.printf("%d quarters, %d dimes, %d nickels, %d pennies\n",
              quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);
}
// Don't change the code below.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean done = false;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!done) {
        System.out.println("Enter a # between 1 and 99 (0 to stop):");
        int amount = in.nextInt();
        if (amount <= 0) {
            done = true;
        } else {
            makeChange(amount);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You have just copied and pasted some code, code that is wrong by the way, and not calculated any of the other values dimes, nickels & pennies.

Answer (score -3):

Your code is already doing what you are telling it do

inside your makeChange funcion, you are setting all 4 output values as 0 so
your last print statement in this function is displaying 0

You need to put the following line before the last print statement in that function:

```
quarters = amount/25; amount = amount - quarters/25;
```

And then add other lines to calculate remaining values

Comment: First of all you have only pasted code that was included in the question, second that code is incorrect and thirdly "add other lines" is not a helpful way to answer a question.